# Rosemary leaves yellowing at tips

Tags: transplanting, cuttings, rosemary

I took cuttings of this rosemary plant, and put them into a aquaponic bath. It took several months but they rooted and then a month ago I transplanted then into potting mix. However a month later the transplants leaf tips are yellowing. What might be the issue? Ambient temperature is about 10 deg C in mid autumn, and parent plant is still doing well.

[image: Parent rosemary]

[image: Offspring]

Comment: I think it just need time to make roots and growth. I got similar patterns on very dry late summer/fall,

Comment: I've brought the plant inside to see how it goes in warmer temperatures, and away from the drenching rains we have had recently.

Comment: How did this work out for you?

Comment: @J.Musser   It recovered fine, grew very well, and then was given away as a present!

Comment: Guess it was just transplant shock, then

Comment: Seems very late for transplant shock as it started a month after being transplanted from aquaponic to soil.

Comment: Did it grow in that month?

Comment: That I don't recall :(

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the time the second photograph was taken the plant was drenched in water. [Rosemary and Water](http://www.gardenersworld.com/forum/problem-solving/rosemary-and-water/343408.html) at Gardenersworld.com links overwatering with yellowing of the tips.

It also suggests "Rosemary doesn't need feeding of any sort, they prefer beneficial neglect, full sun and very well drained soil in summer, almost sand."

[*Rosmarinus officinalis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary) is a native plant of the Mediterranean and Asia and likes dry conditions. [Rosemary prefers a light soil, a sandy soil will fully satisfy its meagre feeding needs. Having said that, rosemary is tolerant of most soil conditions as long as they are not water-logged. Rosemary prefers a slightly limey soil (the opposite of acid) because this results in smaller plants with more fragrant leaves. True to its origins, rosemary prefers sunny and sheltered conditions.](http://www.gardenaction.co.uk/fruit_veg_diary/fruit_veg_mini_project_july_3_rosemary.asp)

For planting the same site recommends mixing standard potting compost with 20% sharp sand or grit, which helps drainage.

Bringing the plant indoors may have worked by keeping it drier.